# Apply the same commands to many variables

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a .txt file with 100 lines (AAAA.txt). On each line there is a text string, for example:

```
1. P0000
2. A0022
3. N2039

etc...
```

I want each of these strings to become a variable in a batch file, for example (fantasy):

```
set "VAR1=P0000"
# here many many commands on VAR1

set "VAR2=A0022"
# here many many commands on VAR2

set "VAR3=N2039"
# here many many commands on VAR3

etc...
```

So the question is: I need to create a batch with 100 variables (one for each string from AAAA.txt) or can I create a batch that executes the commands on the **first** string of AAAA.txt, then on the **second** string of AAAA.txt, then on the **third** string of AAAA.txt and so on?

Comment: The main problem with what you've currently posted is that there is a maximum character limit for the entire environment. If `VAR1=P0000` being 10 characters, and `1000` of those, that limit would easily be exceeded. You aren't really just using `echo` with `%VARn%` multiple times, so please try to better explain the real task, show us what you are wanting to execute as a command against each line, and we'll try to help you locate an existing question, or assist you in adapting a single line, something like this: ```For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("MyFile") Do @"YourCommand" "%%G"```.

Comment: i've edited the post, please read again and let me know if you understand now, many thanks.

Comment: So based on my previous comment, 1. ```@For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("C:\Somewhere\AAAA.txt") Do @(```, 2. ```"YourFirstCommand" "%%G"```, 3. ```"YourNextCommand" "%%G"```, 4. ```"YourLastCommand" "%%G"```, 5. ```)```. Where each time ```%%G``` will be a variable holding the content of each line.

Comment: the commands are always the same (they are 70 lines of code)

Comment: You said, "many commands", if it was just the same command each time, then it's just one command, and my first comment code stands.